# does lycra turn cyclists into douchebags?

Tags: clothes

Most cyclists I encounter are polite. But the ones wearing lycra are almost always douchebags. They shout things like "hey stop walking in the bike lane" and "use your damn turn signal!" when I'm just minding my own business.

I know some materials like plastics are toxic and toxins can leech in through the skin. Is there something in lycra that damages cyclists' brains that causes them to be douchebags? I'm thinking of starting a campaign to ban lycra and I want to know if it's really the cause of all this douchery or if it just correlates with it.

Comment: Scientific studies have shown the percentage of lycra wearing douchebags in the cycling population is the same as douchebags in the general population. One interesting observation of the study was the majority of the  time social interaction deteriorated between groups was when lycra wearing douchebags came into contact with non-lycra wearing douchebags, most other times the interactions between the groups remained civil.

Comment: I wear lycra, but I hide it under my normal pants and a high vis vest.

Comment: 'Minding your own business' isn't grounds for ignoring vehicular laws.

Comment: If by "minding your own business" you mean creating a dangerous situation for everyone by "walking in the BIKE lane" & by not using your turn signal while... you know... TURNING. Umm yeah, I guess that’s exactly what minding your own business means. Also called being oblivious to the world around you & possibly having an over developed sense of entitlement.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about sanitary equipment.

Comment: If they shout at you while you're 'just minding (your) own business' it is probably because a) you're putting them in a dangerous situation or b) you're putting yourself in a dangerous situation which is certainly the same as sub a).

Comment: @andy256 - I agree that the tone makes it off-topic, but this is the exact rhetoric forwarded by some mainstream media outlets (e.g., UK media) so it may be worth addressing.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles Stack Exchange! This question appears to be an attempt to incite an argument or start a discussion, and not a genuine question. If you'd like it re-opened, please rephrase with less offensive (and non-sexist) language, and make it clearer what *constructive* and *answerable* question you have. Reading these pages may help: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: I think it should be deleted rather than closed. Or edited into something significantly less offensive. As it is it's polluting the site

Answer (score 8):

No.  People with questionable social skills likely were that way long before they put Lycra on. I personally  wear Lycra while commuting because I ride long distances (~50km day) and I have been doing so for 20 years.  I just phoned three long-time friends and all have confirmed that I have yet to turn into a "douchbag." (I would like to point out that this is a horribly sexist term - if we want to instead objectify male genitalia as an insult consider the Red Dwarf classic "smeg head")

I think there are two main components to your observation/complaint:

1. In-group vs out-group dynamics
2. Type A personalities

Let's start with (1),  psychology studies have shown that we tend to classify people we don't identify with as "other" and treat them differently (usually worse) and view the other as this cohesive group (which they are not).  Where we may give an in-group a "pass" on bad behavior, we would not do the same for the out-group. Many do not identify with cyclists nor  Lycra -  combing the two makes an out-out group.  Some of your comments and perspectives reflect this mentality.

As to point (2).  Lycra is clothing designed for performance, not fashion. Most wearing it are performance minded.  A high proportion of performance minded individuals will be the classic type A personality.  Many type A personalities tend to speak their mind directly and have little interest in playing more of an ambassador role.  I am sure this has also contributed to your perception.

*Note: As an aside, bike lanes purposed  for cycling, just as sidewalks are purposed for walking and not cycling.  All vehicles (motorized or self-propelled) are required to use turn signals. Finally, I will add links to the in-group/out-group research when I am back on my computer*

Comment: Very nice answer. In fairness, another possibly relevant aspect of group psychology might be the effects that wearing a "uniform" can have on the mind of the wearer, allowing for "acting out" in ways that might not happen otherwise...

Comment: @junkyardsparkle - I would think that could be the case if authority came with the uniform (I.e. Race team vs club member) but I would need convincing for Lycra in general.  Also we need to be careful as "uniform" can also mean out-group membership and we are subconsciously wired to be suspicious of the out-group.

Comment: I got a kick out of "smeg head". Douche(bag) the pejorative has nothing to do with male genitalia though. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douche

Comment: @GrantSanders - Correct, I was referring to douchbag as being sexist because  most insults focus on female genitalia.  So to help change the times I suggested a male genitalia insult to use in place of.